# Elements removed after execute Comparator in TreeSet

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

I have this peace of code:

```
final SortedSet<NisType> lAllNNisType = new TreeSet<NisType>(new NisTypeComparator());
lAllNisType.addAll(pAllNisType); // where pAllNisType is of type ArrayList<NisType>
```

thats my comparator class:

```
  private class NisTypeComparator implements Comparator<NisType> {

    @Override
    public int compare(NisType pNisType, NisType pNisType2) {
       if (pNisType.getPrio()>pNisType2.getPrio())
         return 1;
       else if (pNisType.getPrio()<pNisType2.getPrio())
         return -1;
       else
         return 0;
    }
  }
```

My ArrayList `pAllNisType` is filled with 6 different objects(based on the equals and hashCode method).
Nevertheless after this line was executed:

```
lAllNisType.addAll(pAllNisType);
```

`lAllNisType` contains only 5 objects.
There is one comparison that returns 0. And as a result of this one object was removed from `lAllNisType`.

I have no idear what happens here. 
The objects are different. If I do something like that:

```
final Set<NisType> lAllNisType = new HashSet<NisType>(pAllNisType);
```

`lAllNisType` has 6 elements.

Thanks for your help

Stefan

Comment: Then your `Comparator` is comparing differently than your `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: of course it is. why is that important?

Comment: That explains why you'd have 5 elements in a `TreeSet` and 6 in a `HashSet`.

Comment: does return 0 mean that the element exists already in the list?

Comment: @StefanBeike: 0 means that two elements are equal - and a set cannot contain two elements which are equal, by definition.

Comment: ok I thought the equal method is the master also in a TreeSet.
Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is behaving precisely as [documented.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if the sorted set is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See the Comparable interface or Comparator interface for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted set performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or compare) method, **so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted set, equal**. The behavior of a sorted set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.

If `compare` is returning 0, then two of your elements are deemed equal as far as the set is concerned, and only one of them can occur in the set. If you want to retain both objects, you'll need to make your comparator differentiate between them, e.g. through a secondary ordering.